# Add multiple colors in axis.text.x names of a ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame:

```
gene_symbol<-c("DADA","SDAASD","SADDSD","SDADD","ASDAD","XCVXCVX","EQWESDA","DASDADS","SDASDASD","DADADASD","sdaadfd","DFSD","SADADDAD","SADDADADA","DADSADSASDWQ","SDADASDAD","ASD","DSADD")
panel<-c("growth","growth","growth","growth","big","big","big","small","small","dfgh","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","gh","DF","DF")
ASDDA<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDb<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf1<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf2<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf3<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf4<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf5<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDA1<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDb1<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf1<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf11<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf21<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf31<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf41<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf51<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
Gene_states22<-data.frame(gene_symbol,panel,ASDDA,ASDDb,ASDDAf,ASDDAf1,ASDDAf2,ASDDAf3,ASDDAf4,ASDDAf5,ASDDA1,ASDDb1,ASDDAf1,ASDDAf11,ASDDAf21,ASDDAf31,ASDDAf41,ASDDAf51)
```

and I create a heatmap:

```
library(ggplot2); library(reshape2)
HG3 <- split(Gene_states22, Gene_states22$panel)
HG4 <- melt(HG3, id.vars= c("gene_symbol","panel"))
HG4 <- HG4[,-5]
HG4$gene_symbol = factor(HG4$gene_symbol, levels = unique(HG4$gene_symbol))

pp <- ggplot(HG4, aes(gene_symbol,variable)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value),
            colour = "grey50") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("white", "red", "blue", "black", "yellow", "green", "brown")) +
  labs(title = "Heatmap", x = "gene_symbol", y = "sample", fill = "value") +
  guides(fill = FALSE)+
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA),
        panel.spacing = unit(0.5, "lines"), ## It was here where you had a 0 for distance between facets. I replaced it by 0.5 .
        strip.placement = "outside",
        axis.text.x = element_text(family = "Calibri", 
                                   size = 11,angle = 45, hjust = 1,color = "red"))


 ggplotly(pp)
```

I would like to know if it is possible to have multiple colors in `axis.text.x` names instead of one based either on the `panel` type they belong or their position (for example first four will be red). Right now they are colored red but I would like to have 6 fifferent colors as many as the `panel` types. Note that the x.axis.names are placed according to the alphabetical order of the `panel` they belong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added `axis.text.x = element_text(family = "Calibri",size = 11,angle = 45,hjust = 1,color = as.factor(panel)))`. Do you need something like that :

```
pp <- ggplot(HG4, aes(gene_symbol,variable)) + 
geom_tile(aes(fill = value),
        colour = "grey50") + 
scale_fill_manual(values = c("white", "red", "blue", "black", "yellow", "green", "brown")) +
labs(title = "Heatmap", x = "gene_symbol", y = "sample", fill = "value") +
guides(fill = FALSE)+
theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA),
    panel.spacing = unit(0.5, "lines"), ## It was here where you had a 0 for distance between facets. I replaced it by 0.5 .
    strip.placement = "outside",
    axis.text.x = element_text(family = "Calibri", 
                               size = 11,angle = 45, hjust = 1,color = as.factor(panel)))
pp
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution works but not with ggplotly(pp). My bad I did not not included this.I edited.

Comment: I accepted your answer since it covers the initial question and I opened another issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51538933/multiple-axis-text-x-names-coloring-does-not-work-with-ggplotly