# Multiple axis.text.x names coloring does not work with ggplotly()

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

I have a data frame:

```
HG44 <- data.frame( gene_symbol = c("sads","sdsds","sdasdad","dfds","sdsdd"), panel = c("big","gr","sm","big","big"), variable = c("x","x","y","z","y") , value = c("normal","over","low","normal","low") , colors = c("red","green","yellow","red","red"))
```

And I create a heatmap with:

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

pp <- ggplot(HG44, aes(gene_symbol,variable)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(family = "Calibri", 
                                   size = 11,angle = 45, hjust = 1,color = as.factor(colors)))

ggplotly(pp)
```

As you can see I use multiple colours according to the `panel` type to color the x-axis names. The problem is that when I use `ggplotly()` this disappears. An alternative would be to color the xaxis names according to the `colors` instaed of panel. The main issue is still `ggplotly()`

Comment: still too much code, but I won't downvote now - why don't you just simply give sample data in the shape of your final HG4 dataframe??? This would reduce the question by 50%

Comment: I could but honestly I think may help the reader understand how this is built and understand better the issue. Anyway I think that the main issue remains here. If this is helpful I could re-edit.

Comment: I personally think that one understands the data well enough with the final version. Think the steps to it are redundant and confusing - but personal taste probably

Comment: I edited according your suggestion.

Comment: Now you still need to specify your color vector as previously :D

Comment: Without knowing too much about ggplotly, I get the impression that the main problem is that you do not map any aesthetics to your x-axis labels (which I don't know if this is possible at all, I don't think so), but you are assigning colors based on a vector. but ggplotly (to my very basic understanding) uses the `aes()`-mapping as defined in your other plot calls (`ggplot()`/ `geom_xxx`) for identifying differences. A workaround could be to create a plot that looks like axis labels and then bind those plots

Comment: I have little knowledge on plotly and this why I asked for some help from an expert.

Comment: Your code gives me an error. This `+ 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(family = "Calibri", 
                                   size = 11,angle = 45, hjust = 1,color = as.factor(colors)))` throws me an error.

Comment: remove color=as.factor(colors)